# SHA1 C# result different from Python 3

Tags: c#, python, python-3.x

I have this code on C#:

```
public static string GenerateSecureHash(string data) {
    HashAlgorithm algorithm = SHA1.Create();
    byte[] hash = algorithm.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data)); 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (byte b in hash) 
        sb.Append(b.ToString("x2"));

    return sb.ToString(); 
}
```

Which generates an SHA1 String given a `data` string. I tried converting this to Python3 with the following code:

```
def GenerateSecureHash(data: str):
    print('Generate Secure Hash called!')

    enc = str.encode('utf-8') # encode in utf8
    hash = sha1(enc)
    formatted = hash.hexdigest()

    return formatted
```

But they give different outputs.

For example, if I feed in "testStringHere", here are the outputs:

```
C#: 9ae24d80c345695120ff1cf9a474e36f15eb71c9
Python: 226cf119b78825f1720cf2ca485c2d85113d68c6
```

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: can you post the hex inputs? sha is not case insensitive.

Comment: This should help. Shows similar question with an answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44151439/cannot-get-same-hash-in-c-sharp-as-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is at here,

```
enc = str.encode('utf-8')
```

By doing this you are actually encoding the string "**utf-8**" with the default encoding 'utf-8'(not the '"**testStringHere**"' string).

```
>>> str.encode("utf-8")
b'utf-8'
```

See the documentation of `str.encode`

```
>>> help(str.encode)
Help on method_descriptor:

encode(self, /, encoding='utf-8', errors='strict')
    Encode the string using the codec registered for encoding.

    encoding
      The encoding in which to encode the string.
    errors
      The error handling scheme to use for encoding errors.
      The default is 'strict' meaning that encoding errors raise a
      UnicodeEncodeError.  Other possible values are 'ignore', 'replace' and
      'xmlcharrefreplace' as well as any other name registered with
      codecs.register_error that can handle UnicodeEncodeErrors.
```

You could do the encoding by

```
enc = str.encode("testStringHere", 'utf-8') # encode in utf8
```

***OR***

```
enc = "testStringHere".encode('utf-8') # encode in utf8
```

Demo:

```
>>> from hashlib import sha1
>>> enc = str.encode("testStringHere", 'utf-8')
>>> enc1 = "testStringHere".encode('utf-8')
>>> sha1(enc).hexdigest() == sha1(enc1).hexdigest()
True
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect the issue is the way you're converting the bytes back to a string.

Maybe try something like this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1003289/813503

```
string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray);
```